# RecyclerView with Alphabet indext in xamarin android

Tags: xamarin.android

can anyone please help me with this I want to implement the Alphabetic index with Recyclerview in Xamarin android.

Comment: You can create a custom view and Make the view like this layout https://github.com/Poke-MMo/SortRecyclerView/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml You can refer to this demo:https://github.com/Poke-MMo/SortRecyclerView  convert the java code to C# code.

Answer (score 0):

You must first sort our list

example:

```
 List<Email> emails = new List<Email>();
    emails.Add(new Email { Address="Test1@contoso.com" , CreateTime=new DateTime(2016, 7, 14, 3, 15, 0) });
    emails.Add(new Email { Address = "Test2@contoso.com", CreateTime = new DateTime(2013, 8, 11, 3, 15, 0) });
    emails.Add(new Email { Address = "Test3@contoso.com", CreateTime = new DateTime(2017, 6, 13, 3, 15, 0) });
    emails.Add(new Email { Address = "Test4@contoso.com", CreateTime = new DateTime(2011, 8, 14, 3, 15, 0) });
    emails.Add(new Email { Address = "Test5@contoso.com", CreateTime = new DateTime(2013, 9, 16, 3, 15, 0) });
    emails.Add(new Email { Address = "Test6@contoso.com", CreateTime = new DateTime(2015, 1, 15, 3, 15, 0) });

    emails.Sort((x, y) => DateTime.Compare(x.CreateTime, y.CreateTime));

    var recyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(emails, this);
    recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.SetAdapter(adapter);
```